# Is polystyrene sun/heat/frost-resistant?

Tags: materials

I'd like to put my weather station into the polystyrene hermetic case but my concerns are around whether it is going to survive in the sun, heat and frost. The vendor says it is not intended to be used in such conditions and this is probably where I should finish with PS case but I have some of those and want to spend no extra money.

Currently I am testing such case for a week or so and it seems it can stand being frozen to ~-18 deg C., then getting heated to room temperature, wet and then frozen again and again. No cracks, no deformations. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

It will die in the sun. It may take a few months, but it will die. Listen to the vendor.

Comment: This is definitely something I cannot simulate/test at home with no extra equipment, thanks! Found some [interesting link](http://engr.bd.psu.edu/young/PLET%20206W/Quiz/Combo.doc) listing the pros and cons of particular plastic materials.

Comment: I will go for a polycarbonate case which is claimed by the seller as weather conditions-resistant, including UV. And to make some experiment I will leave the sensors in the PS case to see what will happen after a year or so (cheap ones).